# How can spineplot plot ggplot2-like stacked bar charts?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Section 6.2 of [A Layered Grammar of Graphics](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/layered-grammar.pdf) says the following:

> In  the  grammar,  a  pie  chart  is  a  stacked  bar  geom  drawn  in  a  polar  coordinate system.

Similarly, the documentation for ggplot2's `coord_polar` says:

> ```
> #' # A pie chart = stacked bar chart + polar coordinates
> pie <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(cyl))) +
>  geom_bar(width = 1)
> pie + coord_polar(theta = "y")
> ```

Running only the first line of their code, I get the following graph.
[image]

The documentation for `spineplot` (base R, not ggplot), says:

> Spine plots are a special cases of mosaic plots, and can be seen as a generalization of stacked (or highlighted) bar plots.

After reading this, I thought that I would be able to get `spineplot` to generate a graph like the stacked bar chart above. However, I have failed in every attempt. For various reasons, all of the following throw errors:

```
spineplot(table(mtcars$cyl))
spineplot(prop.table(mtcars$cyl))
spineplot(factor(mtcars$cyl))
spineplot(mtcars$cyl,nrow(mtcars))
spineplot(factor(mtcars$cyl),nrow(mtcars))
spineplot(nrow(mtcars),factor(mtcars$cyl))
```

This is much unlike base R's `pie(table(mtcars$cyl))` and `mosaicplot(table(mtcars$cyl))` which both work without complaint, but do not show the counts for each variable.

So, is it possible to get `spineplot` to generate the desired stacked bar chart? Or do I have some misunderstanding over what a spineplot is? The article linked earlier also claims that "*A bullseye chart is the polar equivalent of the spineplot*" and that a pie chart is just a transformed bullseye plot, so there definitely should be some very strong relationship between spineplots and stacked bar charts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A spineplot requires two variables, so to plot `mtcars$cyl` you need to add another variable, e.g. `mtcars$gear`:

```
spineplot(table(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$gear))
```

[image: example_1.png]

The [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/spineplot) go into more detail and have some good examples of potential uses for this type of plot.

--

Another example; Horsepower is related to the number of cylinders. This is the typical format: "variable (factor), tilde, variable (factor or continuous)":

```
spineplot(factor(mtcars$cyl) ~ mtcars$hp,
          xlab = "Horsepower",
          ylab = "Number of Gears",
          main = "Spineplot: mtcars dataset")
```

[image: example_2.png]

--

I don't believe it's possible to draw a spineplot like the one in your example. The relationship between spineplots and stacked barplots is as quoted in your question: *"spine plots are a special case of mosaic plots, and can be seen as a generalization of stacked (or highlighted) bar plots"*. They are essentially two stacked barplots combined to show the proportion of two variables in contrast to each other via the widths of the bars (like a mosaic plot). I think the best way to plot the proportion of values for a single variable is to use a stacked barplot, e.g.

```
par(xpd = TRUE)
par(mar=c(2,4,3,6))
mtcars_cyl_percentage <- as.matrix(table(mtcars$cyl)*100/sum(table(mtcars$cyl)))
barplot(mtcars_cyl_percentage, border="white", col = 4:2, main = "Stacked Barplot: mtcars dataset",
        ylab = "Proportion (%)")
legend("topleft", c("8 cylinders", "6 cylinders", "4 cylinders"),
       inset = c(1, 0), bty = "n", fill = 2:4)
```

[image: example_3.png]

Comment: _"spineplots are **a special case** of a stacked barplot "_. The quotes in my question appear to directly contradict you e.g.: "_Spine plots are a special cases of mosaic plots, and can be seen as **a generalization** of stacked (or highlighted) bar plots._".

Comment: Right - sorry - the quote in your question (_"Spine plots are a special cases of mosaic plots, and can be seen as a generalization of stacked (or highlighted) bar plots."_) is more accurate - I'll update my answer